# Reference an Excel Sheet Name with a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function:

```
Public Function getLastRow(sheetName As String) As Integer
    getLastRow = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
End Function
```

When I try to use that function . . .

```
Sub test()
MsgBox getLastRow("Data")
End Sub
```

. . . I get a subscript out of Range (run-time error '9') error. How can I make the error go away?

running `getLastRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row` works fine. But I want to be able to dynamically choose the sheet name in my function.

Comment: Works fine for me too. Can you provide more info about your Excel version?
Additionally you can try to split the expression into several parts to see where the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, strange. I just copied the two functions to a blank workbook, and it worked, but is not working on my other workbook.

Comment: Are you sure the worksheet is called "Data"? For example, there's no whitespace before or after it? That could be the reason the "subscript out of range" occurs.

Comment: It now works on my other workbook! I'm not crazy, I swear. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is because incorrect workbook is activated.

try this:

```
Public Function getLastRow(sheetName As String) As Integer
    getLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

or

```
Public Function getLastRow(workbookName As String, sheetName As String) As Integer
    getLastRow = Workbooks(workbookName).Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```